# I want to exclude (minus) 7% from a column in a table, like an discount. How can I do that in SQL language?

Tags: sql-server

`Select Price(Example) from Products` and then? I was wondering if I can use something like `Price-7% update Price`, or something along those lines...

Comment: Without any context it seems you simply need an expression like: (price * 0.93)

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and take the tour.

Comment: You can setup compute column in Products table which will be price * 0.93